# Tracing in c# to write trace in same order method are called in 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, .net, interceptor

I am working on 3tier architecture application. 
In which `A()` method in 1st layer calls `B()` method in 2nd layer which calls `C()` method in 3rd layer and in opposite sequence they return the response.

In each method i am using StringBuilder to create a string trace of method execution and writes it using Microsoft Enterprinse library to in finally block.

```
A()
{
  string.append("A() method started");
  B();
  string.append("A() method finished");
}

B()
{
  string.append("B() method started");
  C();
  string.append("B() method finished");
}

C()
{
  string.append("C() method started");
  some...task;
  string.append("C() method finished");
}
```

then the trace is:

```
string.append("C() method started");  
string.append("C() method finished");  
string.append("B() method started");  
string.append("B() method finished");  
string.append("A() method started");  
string.append("A() method finished");
```

which is in reverse order. But I want

```
string.append("A() method started");  
string.append("B() method started");
string.append("C() method started");
string.append("C() method finished");
string.append("B() method finished");
string.append("A() method finished");
```

So what is the best way or any library to do the same. I was suggested to use interceptor approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I would agree to that suggestion. You can try using Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) where you can do Method Interception. [Although you can do this via reflection and some other namespaces.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8436/Intercepting-method-calls-in-C-an-approach-to-AOSD) but it's a pain in the ass to do.

Although, by default C# is not a AOP language, there are libraries available to apply AOP concepts to C#. One is [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/). I believe you can get a trial/free version of this. I find it easy to use and pretty straightforward.